# How to connect a computer in LAN?

Tags: networking

A----NAT1----NAT2----B

I want to connect to B from A, for example ssh to B

I can do nothing to routers

How to do that?

Comment: You should be able to SSH from B to A, establishing an SSH tunnel, then SSH BACK to B from A. Only way I can think of without using port forwarding, but I'm not too tech savvy

Comment: You need a server somewhere on the Internet that both A and B can setup SSH tunnels (or VPN connections) to. Amazon will give you a free EC2 micro instance if nothing else. Hurricane Electric will give you free IPv6 tunnels which you can use like a VPN.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. it's impossible (that's assuming that behind the NAT A and B are using private IP ranges (RFC1918)).